# How i can get weather forecast from yahoo android

Tags: java, android, weather

How i can get weather forecast from yahoo android
I want to make app weather forecast

```
first page 
-show current location and weather location
-show weather forecast of week
```

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo provides a dynamically generated RSS feed.
http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/ which includes weather forecast and you can query for specified location.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how can i coding it. i am newby

Comment: are u on gtalk chatting with me

Comment: There is a lot to tell you in this case! You need to parse first the RSS feed. It's based on request - response. To start with you can use [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). But to be more specific about Android or mobile platforms, using jQuery mobile will help you the best. [Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/) you can see how it's done.